# Ubuntu crashes while booting (Dual Boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, lenovo

I Dual booted Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 along with pre installed Windows 11.

I was facing WiFi problem as it says no WiFi adaptor was found. I tested many "solutions" that didn't work for me, and I tried to disable "*Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power*" on my WiFi card in Windows.

When this setting is disabled and I try to boot Ubuntu, it just crashes.
What should I do?

Comment: Please list all the things you have tried and the results. Otherwise all anyone might do is repeat what you have already tried. Please do not answer in comments, edit the question and add the info.

Answer (score 0):

I Zack, Wifi card still work in windows after ubuntu problem?

I have an Desktop and dedicated wifi card,have same problem but in windows still no wifi card too.

My solution was to kill all power on pc. Power off system then remove cable power and power on the machine to kill all energy on motherboard.
It works for me but you have laptop... So,do the same without battery. In some cases you need to remove the CMOS battery too.

Hope it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem. What I did is:
[1] Boot into Windows
[2] Disable wifi before shutting down/restarting
[3] Boot into Ubuntu
I am not a technical expert and I dont know how this works, but it just works!